# Mercurial Backout command

Tags: mercurial

Im trying to run the following command but its producing errors.

> hg backout -r 2 -u Fraz --merge

The log of my repository is as follows:

[image]

Im a little lost as to why i can back out the 2nd changeset. When i run the above command, i get the commit gui appearing, i add a comment, save, close. Then i get a merge error, see below. Could someone please explain why this is happening?

[image]

**EDIT** seems to have something to do with the .bak file i had. Ive just rerun it via notepad and no errors occured. Also note, my comment on the first proposed answer is wrong. It adds a new changeset to repository which specifically undo's the specified changeset, hence why a merge is then necessary as u have two heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backout is not undo - it basically allows to re-apply a changeset in reverse, undoing the changes of it.

Now if changes were done to the parts changed in the changeset to be backed out, you'll have to deal with the merge as you see it because the backout cannot be automatically applied (what should happen with the portions that are to be backed out but changed since the commit of the changeset to be backed out?).

After resolving the conflicts you should be able to successfully complete the operation.